# Android Play Store - Stop my application from automatically updating

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application on the Android Play Store.  I also have a Windows based application (service).  My users install the service on their PCs, and they install the Android application on their mobile devices.  These send data back and forth.

I have an update for both applications.  If I update JUST ONE, it will not work.

My preferred method - is this possible?:
 - Upload a new APK to the marketplace
 - Somehow flag it so that auto update is OFF
 - When users click to install, I'd like a massive warning "Requires XXXXXXX" telling them to update their Windows Service as well.

Has anyone else ran into this?  Did you do it like I'm looking to do?  If not, how did you go about it?

I suppose I could rename the mobile application and tell users to install it during the install of the newer Windows service.  But that would leave the old application out there as well, and I like the idea of updating it; not having two installed.

So the question is - Is that possible or not, and if not, what's a better route to go?

Comment: Make the applications backwards compatible? Or at least give a warning that they need to update the other, if they are out of sync?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to prevent the update notifications.

One option you have though is to have the PC side communicate its version to the Android side and inside your Android app build it to be backwards compatible so that if the updated app see's that the PC client is old it will continue to use the old methods for interacting with the PC.

And only if it sees that the PC client has also been updated will it start to use the new interactions.

This would also allow you to inform the user that their version of the PC app is out of date and that the should update it to get the most out of the Android app.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was figuring.  I don't make the other service; other developers do.  And the reason for not wanting backwards compatibility is because the other service is being completely removed in place of a new one that will get installed.  So technically either mobile application version will function, but I don't want people updating my application if they don't have the right service.  Also, we do want to remove the old windows service and not leave two out there.  I think we'll end up making this mobile version a new application.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you mention does not seem possible.

**Alternate workflow:**

- I have seen this application [Unified Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Relmtech.Remote&hl=en) which has requirements similar to yours. 
  When the application is opened for the first time, it just urges the user to install the server-software on their PC.
- I think that is an elegant solution, rather than showing a **warning in ALLCAPS or bold**, which don't contribute towards a very good user experience.
- If the user tries to connect to an old version of the PC application, with the new version of Android application, you can issue a friendly error which urges the user to update the desktop application.

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like this would only resolve a symptom of a problem and not the problem itself. Why does your application break when the updates are out of sync? You are asking for a lot of involvement from the user to keep both up to date at all times.

Ideally your network communications, and I am assuming this is the problem, should be backwards compatible. If you look at protocol libraries such as ProtoBuf you will find that a lot of thought has been given to ensuring various versions of an application are able to communicate successfully. This route would allow your applications to be out of sync with versions and allow each to recognize which application is out of sync and notify the user accordingly that a new version of said software should be updated for all features to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Visual Basic to create the Windows service, or is it Java based (using different IDE)? Either way, you should be able to update them individually without breaking their relationship. But if they both need to update, I believe that Visual Basic has a way to export your application so that it automatically checks for updates at a particular URL. When you upload the APK to the market place, upload the updated windows project to the place you've assigned. The Windows service should then detect the update and prompt the user to download and install.
As of yet, I have not come across an app that pops up a "massive warning" when the install button is clicked. You would need to put that in the apps description in ALL CAPS, I guess.